Edit Style.css in Theme Folder on Server
My current procedure for editing Style.css is to use FTP to load the file into an editor on my computer and then save it back to the website server.
I would like to replicate that idea using either Firefox or Chrome developer tools.
When I make the changes, I can see how they work, but I can't find a way to post those changes back to the server.
FTP sees a path to the file using something like "/home/thewebsite/public_html/wp-content/themes/divi_child/style.css. Is there some place I should post that path?
What am I missing?
Thanks.

You can use an FTP client with direct editing capabilities like cyberduck.

This question is similar to: How to persist CSS changes with Chrome Developer Tools. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm specifically referring to this answer to the question: How to persist CSS changes with Chrome Developer Tools
